# Arduino code to make an led strip of 3 blink

Tags: arduino, led

I have an arduino board with an led strip with 3 led plugged into pin 1. a picture of the wiring is below. this is the code I used to attempt to lightup the led, with no luck:

```
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>
#define PIN 1

Adafruit_NeoPixel strip = Adafruit_NeoPixel(3, PIN, NEO_KHZ800);

void setup() {
  strip.begin();
  strip.show();//Initialize all pixels to 'off'

  strip.setbrightness(50);
  forcint i=0; i<3;i++)

  strip.setPixelColor(0,255,255,255);
  strip.show();
}

void loop() {
  for (int i=255;i>=0;i--){
  lightColor(i,0,0);
  delay(10);
  i=i+2
  }
}
```

[image]

any help will be aprecited, this is my first time using arduino

Comment: Pins 0 and 1 are connected to the other MCU on the board; you should not use them unless you know that they are required.

Comment: so should i use pin 13?

Comment: Pin 13 should work, but you may see the  on-board LED flicker as well.

Comment: i have to make code that makes it blink at a set interval

Comment: I think a NeoPixel draws up to 66mA, which is way too much for a single Arduino pin. 3 of them certainly are.

Comment: its definitely possible. because other people are trying to accomplish the same task and have done it successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>
#define PIN 13

Adafruit_NeoPixel strip = Adafruit_NeoPixel(3, PIN, NEO_KHZ800);

void setup() {
  strip.begin();
  strip.show();//Initialize all pixels to 'off'

  strip.setbrightness(50);

  strip.setPixelColor(0,255,255,255);
  strip.show();
}

void loop() {
  for (int i=255;i>=0;i--){
      lightColor(i,0,0);
      delay(10);
  }
  delay(500);
}
```

With this code, LED will decrease RED channel until 0, wait 0'5 seconds and repeat.
I change your setup function by deleting a malformed `for` loop. And in `loop()` I added a delay and removed `i=i+2` bacause I didn't understand its function. And finally, you must use another pin because PIN 1 is for serial use.